# Getting a violates foreign key constraint from PostgreSQL in a AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have two tables, `documents` and `events`. When a document is inserted or updated I would like to update the events table.

```
-- Create the document store table
CREATE TABLE documents (
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  parent TEXT REFERENCES documents,
  data JSONB,
  created TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  updated TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);

-- Create the normalized event table
CREATE TABLE events (
  document TEXT REFERENCES documents,
  type TEXT NOT NULL,
  eventDate date NOT NULL,
  title TEXT,
  subtitle TEXT,
  description TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY(document, type, eventDate)
);
```

I have a helper function and trigger:

```
-- Keep the update documentDB column valid
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_modified_column()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.updated = now();
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_patents_updated BEFORE UPDATE ON documents
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_modified_column();

-- Put a document
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PutDocument(in_data JSON)
RETURNS TEXT AS $$
DECLARE
    r_id TEXT;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO documents (id, parent, data) VALUES (in_data::JSONB->>'id',
      in_data::JSONB->>'parent', in_data::JSONB)
    ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET data=in_data::JSONB RETURNING id
      INTO r_id;
    RETURN r_id;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Then I have the trigger that should update the events table

```
-- Create birthday events
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION document_to_event_birthday()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO events (document, type, eventDate, title, subtitle, description)
    VALUES(NEW.data->'id', 'BIRTH', to_date(NEW.data->'birth'->>'date', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'title', 'subtitle', 'description')
  ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT events_pkey DO NOTHING;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER document_to_event_birthday
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON documents
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE document_to_event_birthday();
```

When I try to insert a document it errors in the `document_to_event_birthday` function.

```
PutDocument('{"id": "ham", "test": "value", "birth": { "date": "2011-06-02" }}');
```

Gives me

```
ERROR:  insert or update on table "events" violates foreign key constraint "events_document_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (document)=("ham") is not present in table "documents".
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO events (document, type, eventDate, title, subtitle, description)
    VALUES(NEW.data->'id', 'BIRTH', to_date(NEW.data->'birth'->>'date', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'title', 'subtitle', 'description')
  ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT events_pkey DO NOTHING"
PL/pgSQL function document_to_event_birthday() line 3 at SQL statement
SQL statement "INSERT INTO documents (id, parent, data) VALUES (in_data::JSONB->>'id',
      in_data::JSONB->>'parent', in_data::JSONB)
    ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET data=in_data::JSONB RETURNING id"
PL/pgSQL function putdocument(json) line 5 at SQL statement
```

If I look at the tables after the error, they are both empty. So my trigger is not happening after the insert/update on the document table.

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a typo in the function `document_to_event_birthday()`: In

```
INSERT INTO events (document, ...)
   VALUES (NEW.data->'id', ...)
```

you should have used

```
NEW.data->>'id'
```

The way the function is coded now, the function tries to insert a `jsonb` value, which implicitly gets converted to `text`. But then the value is `"ham"` rather than `ham` with additional double quotes, which violates the foreign key constraint.